# Integrating a multidimensional integral in scipy

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

**Motivation:** I have a multidimensional integral, which for completeness I have reproduced below. It comes from the computation of the second virial coefficient when there is significant anisotropy:

[image]

Here W is a function of all the variables. It is a known function, one which I can define a python function for.

**Programming Question:** How do I get `scipy` to integrate this expression? I was thinking of chaining two triple quads ([`scipy.integrate.tplquad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html#scipy.integrate.tplquad)) together, but I'm worried about performance and accuracy. Is there a higher dimensional integrator in `scipy`, one that can handle an arbitrary number of nested integrals? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You may be better try [`Sympy`](http://sympy.org).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With a higher-dimensional integral like this, monte carlo methods are often a useful technique - they converge on the answer as the inverse square root of the number of function evaluations, which is better for higher dimension then you'll generally get out of even fairly sophisticated adaptive methods (unless you know something very specific about your integrand - symmetries that can be exploited, etc.)

The [mcint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mcint/) package performs a monte carlo integration: running with a non-trivial `W` that is nonetheless integrable so we know the answer we get (note that I've truncated r to be from [0,1); you'll have to do some sort of log transform or something to get that semi-unbounded domain into something tractable for most numerical integrators):

```
import mcint
import random
import math

def w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma):
    return(-math.log(theta * beta))

def integrand(x):
    r     = x[0]
    theta = x[1]
    alpha = x[2]
    beta  = x[3]
    gamma = x[4]
    phi   = x[5]

    k = 1.
    T = 1.
    ww = w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma)
    return (math.exp(-ww/(k*T)) - 1.)*r*r*math.sin(beta)*math.sin(theta)

def sampler():
    while True:
        r     = random.uniform(0.,1.)
        theta = random.uniform(0.,2.*math.pi)
        alpha = random.uniform(0.,2.*math.pi)
        beta  = random.uniform(0.,2.*math.pi)
        gamma = random.uniform(0.,2.*math.pi)
        phi   = random.uniform(0.,math.pi)
        yield (r, theta, alpha, beta, gamma, phi)


domainsize = math.pow(2*math.pi,4)*math.pi*1
expected = 16*math.pow(math.pi,5)/3.

for nmc in [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000]:
    random.seed(1)
    result, error = mcint.integrate(integrand, sampler(), measure=domainsize, n=nmc)
    diff = abs(result - expected)

    print "Using n = ", nmc
    print "Result = ", result, "estimated error = ", error
    print "Known result = ", expected, " error = ", diff, " = ", 100.*diff/expected, "%"
    print " "
```

Running gives

```
Using n =  1000
Result =  1654.19633236 estimated error =  399.360391622
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  22.0913468345  =  1.35354937522 %

Using n =  10000
Result =  1634.88583778 estimated error =  128.824988953
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  2.78085225405  =  0.170384397984 %

Using n =  100000
Result =  1646.72936 estimated error =  41.3384733174
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  14.6243744747  =  0.8960437352 %

Using n =  1000000
Result =  1640.67189792 estimated error =  13.0282663003
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  8.56691239895  =  0.524899591322 %

Using n =  10000000
Result =  1635.52135088 estimated error =  4.12131562436
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  3.41636536248  =  0.209322647304 %

Using n =  100000000
Result =  1631.5982799 estimated error =  1.30214644297
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  0.506705620147  =  0.0310461413109 %
```

You could greatly speed this up by vectorizing the random number generation, etc.

Of course, you can chain the triple integrals as you suggest:

```
import numpy
import scipy.integrate
import math

def w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma):
    return(-math.log(theta * beta))

def integrand(phi, alpha, gamma, r, theta, beta):
    ww = w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma)
    k = 1.
    T = 1.
    return (math.exp(-ww/(k*T)) - 1.)*r*r*math.sin(beta)*math.sin(theta)

# limits of integration

def zero(x, y=0):
    return 0.

def one(x, y=0):
    return 1.

def pi(x, y=0):
    return math.pi

def twopi(x, y=0):
    return 2.*math.pi

# integrate over phi [0, Pi), alpha [0, 2 Pi), gamma [0, 2 Pi)
def secondIntegrals(r, theta, beta):
    res, err = scipy.integrate.tplquad(integrand, 0., 2.*math.pi, zero, twopi, zero, pi, args=(r, theta, beta))
    return res

# integrate over r [0, 1), beta [0, 2 Pi), theta [0, 2 Pi)
def integral():
    return scipy.integrate.tplquad(secondIntegrals, 0., 2.*math.pi, zero, twopi, zero, one)

expected = 16*math.pow(math.pi,5)/3.
result, err = integral()
diff = abs(result - expected)

print "Result = ", result, " estimated error = ", err
print "Known result = ", expected, " error = ", diff, " = ", 100.*diff/expected, "%"
```

which is slow but gives very good results for this simple case.  Which is better is going to come down to how complicated your `W` is and what your accuracy requirements are.   Simple (fast to evaluate) W with high accuracy will push you to this sort of method; complicated (slow to evaluate) W with moderate accuracy requirements will push you towards MC techniques.

```
Result =  1632.10498552  estimated error =  3.59054059995e-11
Known result =  1632.10498552  error =  4.54747350886e-13  =  2.7862628625e-14 %
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at `mcint` and see if it performs better than my ad-hoc MC method I've got going now.

Comment: @JohnathanDursi is it possible to get a multidimensional Gaussian quadrature in Python? Such quadrature sets are used for instance in solving the heat conduction equation. In this case one distributes the polar angles according to some quadrature rule and the azimuthal angles (directions) are uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 13):

[Jonathan Dursi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075572/10548649) has made a very good answer. I will just add on to his answer.

Now `scipy.integrate` has a function named `nquad` that one can perform a multi-dimensional integral without hassle. See [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad) for more information. Below we compute the integral using `nquad` with Jonathan's example:

```
from scipy import integrate
import math
import numpy as np

def w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma):
    return(-math.log(theta * beta))

def integrand(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma):
    ww = w(r, theta, phi, alpha, beta, gamma)
    k = 1.
    T = 1.
    return (math.exp(-ww/(k*T)) - 1.)*r*r*math.sin(beta)*math.sin(theta)

result, error = integrate.nquad(integrand, [[0, 1],             # r
                                            [0, 2 * math.pi],   # theta
                                            [0, math.pi],       # phi
                                            [0, 2 * math.pi],   # alpha
                                            [0, 2 * math.pi],   # beta
                                            [0, 2 * math.pi]])  # gamma
expected = 16*math.pow(math.pi,5)/3
diff = abs(result - expected)
```

The result is more accurate than the chained `tplquad`:

```
>>> print(diff)
0.0
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll just make a couple of general comments about how to accurately do this sort of integral, but this advice is not specific to scipy (too long for a comment, even though it is not an answer).

I don't know your use case, i.e. whether you are satisfied with a `good' answer with a few digits of accuracy which could be obtained straightforwardly using Monte Carlo as outlined in Jonathan Dursi's answer, or whether you really want to push the numerical accuracy as far as possible.

I've performed analytic, Monte Carlo and quadrature calculations of virial coefficients myself. If you want to do the integrals accurately, then there are a few things you should do:

1. Attempt to perform as many of the integrals exactly as possible; it may well be that integration in some of your coordinates is quite simple.
2. Consider transforming your variables of integration so that the integrand is as smooth as possible. (This helps for both Monte Carlo and quadrature).
3. For Monte Carlo, use importance sampling for best convergence.
4. For quadrature, with 7 integrals it may just be possible to get really fast convergence using tanh-sinh quadrature. If you can get it down to 5 integrals then you should be able to get 10's of digits of precision for your integral. I highly recommend mathtool / ARPREC for this purpose, available from David Bailey's homepage: http://www.davidhbailey.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you mind on elaborating on #2? _A priori_ how do I know what a good transform would be? Since you've done these type of calculations before, any additional input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First to say that I am not that good in math so please be kind. Anyway, here is my try:
Note that in your question there are **6** variables but **7** integrals!?
In `Python` using `Sympy`:

```
>>> r,theta,phi,alpha,beta,gamma,W,k,T = symbols('r theta phi alpha beta gamma W k T')
>>> W = r+theta+phi+alpha+beta+gamma
>>> Integral((exp(-W/(k*T))-1)*r**2*sin(beta)*sin(theta),(r,(0,2*pi)),(theta,(0,pi)),(phi,(0,2*pi)),(alpha,(0,2*pi)),(beta,(0,pi)),(gamma,(0,pi)))  

>>> integrate((exp(-W)-1)*r**2*sin(beta)*sin(theta),(r,(0,2*pi)),(theta,(0,pi)),(phi,(0,2*pi)),(alpha,(0,2*pi)),(beta,(0,pi)),(gamma,(0,pi)))
```

and here is the result:  [LateX code]

```
\begin{equation*}- \frac{128}{3} \pi^{6} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{2 \pi}} - \frac{\pi}{e^{2 \pi}} - \frac{2}{e^{2 \pi}} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{3 \pi}} - \frac{\pi}{e^{3 \pi}} - \frac{2}{e^{3 \pi}} - 3 \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{6 \pi}} - 3 \frac{\pi}{e^{6 \pi}} - \frac{2}{e^{6 \pi}} - 3 \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{7 \pi}} - 3 \frac{\pi}{e^{7 \pi}} - \frac{2}{e^{7 \pi}} + \frac{1}{2 e^{9 \pi}} + \frac{\pi}{e^{9 \pi}} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{9 \pi}} + \frac{1}{2 e^{8 \pi}} + \frac{\pi}{e^{8 \pi}} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{8 \pi}} + \frac{3}{e^{5 \pi}} + 3 \frac{\pi}{e^{5 \pi}} + 3 \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{5 \pi}} + \frac{3}{e^{4 \pi}} + 3 \frac{\pi}{e^{4 \pi}} + 3 \frac{\pi^{2}}{e^{4 \pi}} + \frac{1}{2 e^{\pi}} + \frac{1}{2}\end{equation*}
```

You may play a bit more for your question ;)

Comment: That still looks like it is doing symbolic calculation, i.e. your W is a linear function of the input variables, hence the exact result. For me W is non-linear and not expressible as a math function, but as the result of another calculation (thus defined as a python function). You are correct that I should only have 6 integrals, I must have gotten carried away TeXing it up.