# How to use numpy to compute high-dimensional overlap integral

Tags: python, numpy

Psi is stored as a ND numpy array on a spacial grid (for example if N=2 Psi is a 2D array of complex values). What is the best way to use numpy to compute the following integral:

[image]

I assume it will be a combination of `np.tensordot` and `np.sum`, but I cannot find a way to do it without relying on some heavy loops (problematic for large N).

Comment: You will probably want to use scipy.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14071704/3254859).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
NI = 2*(N-1) # number of integrals
tensor = np.multiply.outer(psi, psi.conj())
for i in range(N):
   axis = -1 if i < N/2 else -2
   tensor = np.sum(tensor, axis=axis)
rho = tensor * dx**N
```