# Using Monte Carlo method to evaluate multiple integrals with multiple variables

Tags: python

My question is very similar to the one this user posted: [Integrating a multidimensional integral in scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071704/integrating-a-multidimensional-integral-in-scipy)

The integral I'm expected to produce a solution for
[can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlsjj.png)

The only issue I'm having when looking at the aforementioned stackoverflow post is that my limits of integration are not constant, they are different for each integral. My first impulse was to just find the solution for each variable (u, v, et cetera) using a more simple version of monte-carlo method of integration for a 1-dimensional integral and then just summing them together. Would this be a valid way of solving a multi-dimensional integrand via Monte Carlo method?

Comment: (1) No, summing them will *not* work; multiplying them would work, once you account for the exponents.  (2) The question you cite also has different integration limits.  It shows you *just* how to do this problem for your case.  (3) You can also solve this with straightforward symbolic integration.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to multiply them and found my answer. Was a bit of work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, summing them will not work; multiplying them would work, once you account for the exponents.
2. The question you cite also has different integration limits. It
   shows you just how to do this problem for your case.
3. You can also solve this with straightforward symbolic integration.